# OpenGL png прозрачная часть текстуры рисуется черным цветом

Tags: c++, opengl, текстура

При попытке нарисовать текстуру, ее прозрачная часть отображается черным цветом:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Вот мой код:

```
    glClearColor(_r, _b, _g, 1.0);
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, _width, 0, _height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.texture);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(x, y);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(x + w, y);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(x + w, y + h);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(x, y + h);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Comment: Тут нужно настроить **смешивание** текстур

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Текстуру загрузил с флагом GL_RGBA? 
Попробуй врубить альфа-тест.

```
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.8f);

//здесь вывод примитива

glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

Вот урок от [NeHe](http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/nehe09.htm)